# Focus cursor in a bubble comment created with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I add a new comment in VBA.

```
Initial = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial
Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = Initial
```

This displays the comment in the right margin in a "bubble". The text entry point remains in the document.

How can I get the text entry point inside the comment bubble?

NOTE: If I use SendKeys to add the comment using the ribbon controls, the text entry focus *is* inside the comment bubble, but I'd rather not use SendKeys as that is liable to go wrong at times.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to declare a `Comment` object and initiate it at the time the comment is created in the document. Note, also, that `Comments.Add` has a parameter for adding text when it's created.

Please also note that the window switching is unnecessary unless you specifically want/need the old Word 2.0 "pane" view (from the time before WYSIWYG existed).

Example:

```
Dim cmt As Word.Comment

Set cmt = ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(Selection.Range, "test")
cmt.Range.Text = cmt.Range.Text & " More text."
```

Comment: Thanks, @Cindy Meister.  Regrettably, this does not solve my difficulty.  I do not have preset text to add--if I did, I agree that it would be simple to use the text parameter to set the comment.  I need to add a blank comment and put the cursor focus there to allow the user to manually type a new comment. As for the "Window Switching," the code changing the View is to prevent the lower pane from appearing with comments--I don't want a lower comment pane; I want the comments in "bubbles" to the right of the document.  That's what the View statements are meant to accomplish.

Comment: @drc and did you try the code I provided, just leaving out the second parameter? The second line shows how to add text to the comment...  And for the balloons, see the VBA Help reference for `View.MarkupMode`

Comment: Yes, I tried the code leaving out the 2nd parameter.  It did not accomplish the goal of opening a balloon comment with the cursor focused in the balloon.  When entered exactly as shown, it creates a balloon comment with the text provided and the cursor focus is still in the main document.  When the text parameter is removed and the " More text" command is omitted, it opens a comment pane at the bottom of the document and the cursor focus is there--I do not want a comment pane at the bottom.

Comment: When I add
     ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.MarkupMode = wdBalloonRevisions
before/after the code to add a comment, a lower comment pane opens and sets the cursor focus in the lower comment pane.  I do not want a lower comment pane at all and I need the focus to be in the empty balloon comment.  Whereas, the code I show in my original post prevents a lower comment pane from opening, but, it does not set the cursor focus in the balloon as I need.  It is setting the cursor focus in the balloon that I still need to accomplish as I have managed to suppress showing a lower comment pane.